# Main table and joined table with note column

Tags: powerbi

really simple question. I have a main table, then a secondary table linked through a key field. On this secondary table there is a notes field. I would like to have the possibility to click on a record on the main table and see the notes associated in the other table, or in a pop up or in the table itself. Is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is standard Power BI behaviour called **cross-filtering**. Didn't you try this out? E.g. take a *Table* visual for your main table and a *Card* Visual for the Notes column of your secondary table, click on a row of the *Table* visual and watch what's happening:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, didn't know this, is working, but I have to double click on every row to show the data on the card. Other than this the card can only show 1 record at a time true? there is no way to show multiple lines?

Comment: Sure. Use a second table instead. Btw, I don't have to double-click.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap! I can recommend a solution:

Here is your data model:

[image: Model View]

Just create a table visual and put Note field on it! then Create a slicer and put Key on the Main table into it! Then you can see the notes by the filter!

[image: GGGF]

Comment: thanks, but can't do this cause the key field on the note table is not univocal, so what I would like is to click on the main table and see all the records inside the note table

Comment: You're welcome, @FrancescoBaldacchini! Please tell me what you mean by word "univocal"?